# covariance issue using shapeless

Tags: scala, shapeless

Consider this snippet:

```
import shapeless.HList

sealed trait Issue[L <: HList] {
  def content: L
  def withT[T](t: T): Issue[T :: L]
}

private case class IssueImpl[L <: HList](content: L) extends Issue[L] {
  def withT[T](t: T)(implicit ev: SomeEvidenceRegardingT[T]): Issue[T :: L] =
    IssueImpl(t :: content)
}
```

What I try to achieve here is to have a structure based on `HList` while restricting what can be put in the `HList` (hence the evidence attached to `withT`)

The problem is that Scala compiler complains that `IssueImpl[T :: L]` does not conform to type `Issue[T :: L]`, but I cant make L covariant in the trait `Issue` as L appears in an invariant position.

Is there a way to have a sound implementation of `Issue`? Or is there another approach which is better suited to what I want to do?

Thanks for any pointer.

Answer (score 1):

I was misdirected by the error message: the problem here is that :: is actually `scala.::` and not `shapeless.::` (it's not imported, only `HList` is).

So the solution is

```
import shapeless.{HList, ::}
```

and `HList` covariance works as intended.